# Generate a column data based on constraints

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv with 2 columns date_1 and date_2.

```
Date_1  Date_2
01/09/2019  02/08/2019
01/09/2019  03/08/2019
02/09/2019  03/08/2019
01/09/2019  04/08/2019
02/09/2019  04/08/2019
03/09/2019  04/08/2019
02/09/2019  05/08/2019
03/09/2019  05/08/2019
04/09/2019  05/08/2019
01/09/2019  06/08/2019
02/09/2019  06/08/2019
03/09/2019  06/08/2019
04/09/2019  06/08/2019
05/09/2019  06/08/2019
02/09/2019  07/08/2019
03/09/2019  07/08/2019
04/09/2019  07/08/2019
05/09/2019  07/08/2019
06/09/2019  07/08/2019
02/09/2019  08/08/2019
03/09/2019  08/08/2019
```

I want to generate a new column `value_1` such that :

1. for each `date_1` the `value_1`(aggregated) should not exceed 5000.
2. `date_2` and `value_1` should have increasing trend i.e. aggregated on `date_2`, `value_1` should be increasing each day for example if for `date_2`, the aggregated `value_1` is 1000, then for next `date_2` the value should be greater than 1000.

The dataframe have unique `(date_1,date_2)` tuples.

EDIT :

Data Link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xOlJfPNhGgclWyyQmdwzG-WRkU2fhEI4/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone help with the same.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Specifically, what is `value_1`

Comment: Your explanation sentence is quite long. Maybe it would be easier to understand if it were split up into a few different sentences?

Comment: @CodeBling value_1 is to be generated using the constraints mentioned.

Comment: As I mentioned, your explanation is not clear. You mention several constraints on `value_1`'s ***aggregated*** value, without mentioning how one obtains `value_1` in the first place. Without understanding this, nobody can help you. (and you will continue to accumulate down-votes, since nobody can understand the question)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is what you really want, but I'm writing it just so you would understand that this fully answers the requirements in your question, and if you meant something else, you would have to add samples of what you expect:

```
df['value_1'] = np.arange(0, 5000 / max(df['date_1'].value_counts()), 5000 / len(df) / max(df['date_1'].value_counts()))
```

This would give you in `value_1` column of an increasing trend, and the sum of `value_1` for each `date_1` is guaranteed not to pass 5000.
btw: to have an increasing trend this assumes your dates are sorted, as in the sample data you posted. If not (or may not), do:

```
df = df.sort_values(['date_1', 'date_2']) # or ['date_2', 'date_1'] if you prefer
```

before the creation of `value_1` column

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the sort is done on the basis of date_2. the column have unique tuple entries(date_1, date_2). Will the same code work then ?

Comment: thank you for your answer and understanding, a couple of queries to it. I tried changed the max limit from 5000 to 25000 and used the following code : `df10['value_2'] = np.arange(50, 25000 / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts()), 25000 / len(df10) / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts()))` I am getting an error saying `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` is there something wrong here. I also want to get the abs values and not the decimal values for the same.

Comment: If you start the `np.arange` from 50 instead of 0, then it should reach `25050 / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts())` for the same steps in the range (don't change them). You can also add `.astype(int)` to the end of the line to get it as ints instead of floats. And yes, it works the same no matter which `date` column is sorted first.

Comment: I changed the code, `df10['value_2'] = np.arange(50, 25050 / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts()), 25050 / len(df10) / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts())).astype(int)` but it still is giving me the same error.

Comment: As I wrote, don't change the step size (the 3rd parameter in the `arange` function), change only the target value (the 2nd parameter).

Comment: I tried the same, still getting the same error. I have uploaded my dataset as well on drive in the edit of the question, I am not sure of what needs to be sorted. the data is sorted on the basis of date_2. The dataset has : for each date_1, there can be multiple date_2. I changed maximum capacity from 5000 to 25000 for date_1. based on your answer and comments,I tried `df10['value_2'] = np.arange(50, 25050 / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts()), 25000 / len(df10) / max(df10['Date_1'].value_counts())).astype(int)` and I am still getting the same error. Can you please help with the same.

Comment: Can you take a look at this?